# Can you install Windows 7 on one partition?

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows Vista and I'm planning to upgrade to Windows 7. Here my data is stored on two partitions, C:\ and D:\ . Most of my data is already in D:\ ; if I install Windows 7 can I install it on C:\ and have it not touch D:\ at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Windows 7 on drive C and that does not affect drive D.

Furthermore, you can select the Upgrade option (if you upgrade from Windows Vista Home Premium to Windows 7 Home Premium etc.) and it does not touch your current data at all. But of course, you should back up your important data on drive C before the upgrade process.

The below chart shows the upgrade options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's what I did on my laptop... Installed on C:, data on D: remained intact.